# Hierarchical List Conversion For Tree View

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of records that I want to display in a tree view, it has a structure like this.

```
public class Account
{
    public string ac_cd { get; set; }
    public string ac_name { get; set; }
    public string ac_parent_cd { get; set; }
    public string ac_nature { get; set; }
}
```

I want to convert this into a hierarchical structure, so assuming I have a list that contains the following items,

ac_cd = "01", ac_name = "Cash", ac_parent_cd = "Null", ac_nature = "Asset",

ac_cd = "02", ac_name = "Supplies", ac_parent_cd = "Null", ac_nature = "Asset",

ac_cd = "01.01", ac_name = "ACME Corp Cash", ac_parent_cd = "01", ac_nature = "Asset",

ac_cd = "02.01", ac_name = "ACME Corp Supplies", ac_parent_cd = "02", ac_nature = "Expense",

ac_cd = "02.01.01", ac_name = "ACME Corp  Office Supplies", ac_parent_cd = "02.01", ac_nature = "Expense",

I want to convert these items into a hierarchical list like this,

01-Cash

---01.01-ACME Corp Cash

02-Supplies

---02.01-ACME Corp Supplies

------02.01.01-ACME Corp Office Supplies

There can be many number of levels for an account. My code so far can only make a child account up to a single level. Here is the POCO of the hierarchical model.

```
public class AccountTree
{
    public string ac_info { get; set; }
    public List<ChildAccount> ac_child { get; set; }
}

public class ChildAccount
{
    public string ac_info { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my code.

```
List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();
        accountList.Add(new Account { ac_cd = "01", ac_name = "Cash", ac_parent_cd = "", ac_nature = "Asset" });
        accountList.Add(new Account { ac_cd = "01.01", ac_name = "Abc Cash", ac_parent_cd = "01", ac_nature = "Asset" });
        accountList.Add(new Account { ac_cd = "01.02", ac_name = "Xyz Cash", ac_parent_cd = "01", ac_nature = "Asset" });

        List<AccountTree> targetAccountList = new List<AccountTree>();
        List<ChildAccount> childAccountList = new List<ChildAccount>();

        foreach (var childAccountGrouping in accountList.GroupBy(o => new { o.ac_parent_cd }))
        {
            if (childAccountGrouping.Key.ac_parent_cd == "")
            {
                continue;
            }

            var childAccounts = childAccountGrouping.ToList();

            foreach (var childAccount in childAccounts)
            {
                childAccountList.Add(new ChildAccount { ac_info = childAccount.ac_cd + childAccount.ac_name + childAccount.ac_nature });
            }

            var parentAccount = (from p in accountList
                                 where p.ac_cd == childAccountGrouping.Key.ac_parent_cd
                                 select p).Single();

            AccountTree accountTree = new AccountTree
            {
                ac_info = parentAccount.ac_cd + parentAccount.ac_name + parentAccount.ac_nature,
                ac_child = childAccountList
            };
            targetAccountList.Add(accountTree);
        }
```

I'm pretty sure I'll have to change this significantly. Would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I would just change the Account class like that:

```
public class Account
{
   public string ac_cd { get; set; }
   public string ac_name { get; set; }
   public Account ac_parent_cd { get; set; }
   public List<Account> ac_children_cd { get; set; }
   public string ac_nature { get; set; }
}
```

now you have easy access to parent and children of all elements